Need help creating two trend lines based on different date columns in Power BI
I have a requirement to show a burn up chart with two trend lines in a line chart in Power BI. First trend line shows the cumulative sum of epics created in a specific year and second trendline should show cumulative  sum of epics closed in that specific year. The two trend lines are based on columns - CreatedDate and ClosedDate.

I have created measure for the first trend line to show epics based on CreatedDate and it works
Measure1 = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(Sheet1),FILTER(ALLSELECTED(Sheet1),Sheet1[CreatedDate]<=MAX(Sheet1[CreatedDate])))

I am not able create a measure to show epics by closed date in the same line chart as its not possible to put both created date and closed date in the x-axis
